# in android proximity alert fired even if the proccess who created it terminated?

Tags: android, gps, location, alert, proximity

In my app at some point i create a proximity alert like this:

```
m_LocationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon,  radius, PROXMITY_ALERT_EXPIRATION_TIME, m_PendingIntent);
```

at some point the procces of my app gets terminated by android, 
i implement these two methods:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

but my alert doesnt fired.., 
my guess is that i need to move the code that creates the alert to a service.

this is the code for setting the alert:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("PROX_ALERT_INTENT"); 
    m_NotificationAlertReciever_BroadcastReciever = new NotificationAlertReciever_BroadcastReciever(m_myLocationListener, this);
    registerReceiver(m_NotificationAlertReciever_BroadcastReciever, intentFilter);

    Intent intent = new Intent("PROX_ALERT_INTENT");
    intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
    intent.putExtra("lng", lon);
    intent.putExtra("place", place);

    m_PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, -1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);   

    this.m_LocationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon,  radius, PROXMITY_ALERT_EXPIRATION_TIME, m_PendingIntent);
```

can sombody approve that or give other advice.

thanks in advance,
Amitos80

Comment: do you have an IntentFilter for this pending intent?

Comment: Yes, i do have an IntentFilter for this pending intent.
Normally if my app is in the foreground there is no problem at all - the intent is fired.

any other ideas?

Comment: What is the action for this intent filter?

Comment: I updated the original question with the code for setting the alert, hope this helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `BroadcastReceiver` is dynamically created from within your activity by using `registerReceiver`.

If you want your process to be re-launched when the proximity alert fires then you must declare the receiver in the `AndroidManifest` like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="PROX_ALERT_INTENT/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now when the proximity alert is fired, if the process doesn't exist it will be started and `MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive` will be invoked.

Note that using the `<receiver>` tag like this isn't possible if your receiver is defined as a nested class in your activity (which is often done so the receiver has direct access to methods and data in the activity).  With a standalone receiver you're pretty much limited to displaying a notification or starting a service.

Also note that the `PROX_ALERT_INTENT` action should really include the application package as a prefix, e.g `my.app.PROX_ALERT_INTENT`.  Not required but it's a convention to keep your actions specific to your app.